# Make sure CSS does not affect all pages with a parent class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got the adminstrator of a webpage that consist of around 20.000 pages. All the pages are using part of the bootstrap components.

I am making and designing some new pages. Therefore I would like to be sure, that i do not change anything global with my CSS. An example can be the row, where I have to make a padding on this one.

I am posting an example of some CSS I am using on the mainpage. In this code the two classes will change things gloabally:

```
.row [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }

.row {
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
  }
```

So is it possible to make some kind of prefix on all my classes? Fx a parents class called `.mk {}`, and then all my classes are going inside this class.

I hope the question make sence - otherwise please tell me that it is unclear where I am going.

```css
#front .row {
    padding-bottom: 0px!important;
  }
  body {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }

  /* Set width between grid elements */
  
  .small-padding.top {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  
  .small-padding.bottom {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .small-padding.left {
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  
  .small-padding.right {
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
  
  .margin_bottom {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .row [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  
  .row {
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
  }
  
  .img-responsive {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  /* Position of buttons/text in a single grid element */
  
  .inner-wrapper {
    background: none;
  }
  
  .centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  
  .bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    right: 16px;
  }
  
  .bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 6%;
  }
/* Position text on full width banner */
  .header-container {
    color: white;
    margin: 0 5%;
  }
  .banner-text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 16%;
    left: 6%;
  }
  
  /* Color on text */
  
  .dark-font {
    color: #333;
  }
  
  .light-font {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .blue-font {
    color: #00a9ff;
  }
   
  /* Set full width on columns */
  
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .img-responsive {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    /* Maybe delete btn-success: */
    .btn-success {
      width: fit-content;
    }
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    h3 {
      font-size: 1.2em;
    }
  }
  .image-overlay {
    position:relative;
  }
  .overlay {
    position:absolute;
    transition:all .3s ease;
    opacity:0;
    transition:1.9s;
    background: #00b1bab8;
  }
  .image-overlay:hover .overlay {
    opacity:1;
  }
  .overlayFade {
    background: rgba(27, 27, 27, 0.5);
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 35px;
  }
```

Comment: There are multiple approaches but a common one is to wrap all your HTML elements in a container with your unique `id` (i.e. `<div id="mkContainer">...</div>` - then all your CSS will need to have that specified (i.e. `#mkContainer .dark-font{...}` ) if you defined it, it will override the parent `.dark-font` but not globally, only on your new pages (with the new container)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is it possible to make some kind of prefix on all my classes?

*Why not?*

Just add some base class to your pages, and create stylesheets that fall under it.

```
<style>
.mk .row [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.mk .row {
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
}
</style>
```

And add your class somewhere close to the body tag, or wherever your changes are different than the site template.

```
<body class="mk">
    <!-- Your code here -->
</body>
```

Doing this will allow you to import all the stylesheets so that you can build on top of them and override with your own styles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I have to set `mk` on all my classes if i define `<body class="mk">
    <!-- Your code here -->
</body>`?

Comment: Just need to set `class="mk"` on a common parent container element that has your fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add prefixes, but I guess instead of overwriting the bootstrap classes by nesting inside your own class name is also not a good idea. i.e.,

```
.custom-class .row {
   // Changing margins and padding here
}
```

Instead, you can make your own `helper` classes for spacing and positioning purposes or if you are already using **Bootstrap v4**, In the utility section they have provided a huge bundle of spacing and positioning classes `.px-*` `.p-*` `.mx-*` `.p-*` etc you can take a look at them  [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/).

Or simply make your own `classes` for different values according to your needs. But I'll still suggest don't overwrite them.

Comment: But no matter what, if I touch the `row` class I am messing with Bootstrap right, because that is a core class from bootstrap? Unfortunately I am forced to work with Bootstrap 3. So take your example, should it look like this: 
`.mk .row {
   // Changing margins and padding here
}`
and the html: `<div class="mk row"`><div class="col-sm-12">text</div></div>. But would I still get the responsive grid Bootstrap is using with the method?

Comment: Using a custom class say `.pad-left-10` gives padding-left of 10 units`(px, if the unit you are using is pixels)`. for all the screen widths. To keep it responsive you can use `rem` units or you need to write media query CSS for your custom class also. Direct messing up with `.row` is not a good idea.